# linear transformation to change $xy+xz+yz$ into $u^2+v^2+w^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Like the title says I have expression : $xy+xz+yz$.

With $x\,\,,\,\,y\,\,,\,\,z\,\,\in \mathbb{C}$.

I found this linear transformation : $(x\,\,,\,\,y\,\,,\,\,z)\mapsto (u\,\,,\,\,v\,\,,\,\,w\,\,) : \mathbb{C} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ :

$ x=-u-i\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}v $

$ y=-i\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}v-w $

$ z=\frac{1}{2}u +\frac{1}{2}w $ .

which gives me : $xy+xz+yz \mapsto u^2+v^2+w^2$

My question: What is the most general form of linear transformations that map $xy+xz+yz$ to $u^2+v^2+w^2$?
Hope someone can help me with this, I don't see how to proceed. Thanks in advance!

NB: Edited question after receiving comments and answers to reflect the fact that we're working in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: It is clear to you that $u,v,w$ (and so also $u^2,v^2,w^2$) will be complex numbers?

Comment: @amsmath Yes, but does that somehow solve it? I'm afraid I'm still missing something here..

Comment: Could you provide some context why is it interesting? Sum of squares for complex numbers is not anything special (unlike real numbers). To your question: given a matrix $Q$ you are interested in finding all $S$ such that $S^TQS=I$. If you know one solution $S_0$, all solutions can be parameterized as $S=S_0X$ where $X^TX=I$.

Comment: @A.Γ. I have a system of three equations, one of which is: $c=xy+xz+yz$. I want to transform this into $1=u^2+v^2+w^2$. Then I can eliminate one variable using polar coordinates. I believe that can be done right? Even when $u\,,v\,,w\in \mathbb{C}$..

Comment: @RutgerMoody It is exactly why sum of squares is not good - since polar coordinates do not work for complex numbers as one is used to think for real numbers. If your original equation is real then use the real transformation to $u^2-v^2-w^2=1$ (see Jean Marie's answer) and then use e.g. hyperbolic coordinates. I guess you can use the polar coordinates on $v,w$ only too.

Comment: @A.Γ. Thx, my idea was this : $\cos^2(\theta) +\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\phi)+\sin^2(\theta)\sin^2(\phi)=1$, this is also true for complex arguments. Using $u^2+v^2+w^2 =1$ I can eliminate 1 of 3 non-linear equations to end up with 2 non-linear equations in $\phi$ and $\theta$. If I can manipulate these into something like $\cos(\phi)=C_1\,\,,\,\,\cos(\theta)=C_2$ then I can solve this by : $\theta=\arccos(C_1)$ etc..

Comment: @RutgerMoody As you wish, but to me it sounds as too much unnecessary work: you first need to do extra work to get sum of complex squares and later you have to do extra work to deal with [complex inverse functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Extension_to_complex_plane). All that can be avoided if you stay totally in the real domain and do hyperbolic parameterization for the equation $u^2-v^2-w^2=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is not the most general solution but a way to determine logically an adequate transformation.

In a first step, a linear transformation with real coefficients can be used on the initial quadratic form (reduction to proper axes), using a kind of Gauss reduction :

$$\left(\frac{x+y+2z}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{x-y}2\right)^2-z^2\tag{1}$$

which has the form $$U^2-V^2-W^2\tag{2}$$ exhibiting a signature (+,-,-) (see an identical development in (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1714385)).

It is important to remark that (2) is as general as (1), therefore can be substituted to it.

In a second step, if we set $U=u$, $V=iv$ and $W=iw$ in (2); we get the desired expression:

$$u^2+v^2+w^2\tag{3}$$

Remark : (1) shows that level sets $xy+yz+zx=k$ are hyperboloids of 2 sheets.

Answer (score 1):

The most general linear transformation is $x = au + bv + cw$, for some constants $a,b,c$ (similarly for $y,z$). So, just use these to get $xy+yz+zx$ in terms of $u,v,w$, and compare coefficients with $u^2+v^2+w^2$ to get the appropriate values of the constants.

Comment: But that gives me a system 3 quadratic equations. How do I solve that for a,b,c etc.?

Comment: So, there will be more unknowns than equations here. Thus, we can choose some coefficients to be zero, until the number of unknowns = number of equations, and solve for them.

Comment: That's how I got the transformation mentioned in the question. But I don't see how that gives me the most general solution.

Comment: The system of equations you had, before setting some variables to zero, is the most general solution. Say, you had 2 equations and 5 unknowns. Then, what you can do is choose 2 variables, and solve for them with respect to the remaining 3 variables. In this case, we will be free to choose the values of 3 coefficients, and have the rest of the coefficients' values fixed by the 2 equations.

Comment: @Ishan Deo I am sorry but your answer is much too vague. Moreover, your reasoning in the last remark doesn't take into account the fact that you cannot assert that for example you have 2 equations : they can be for example redundant leaving only one equation, etc.

Comment: @JeanMarie I think I found the answer: Rotations leave the expression $u^2+v^2+w^2$ invariant right? So take the transformation in the question followed by a general rotation. Wouldn't that be the most general transformation to  map $xy+xz+yz$ to $u^2+v^2+w^2$?

Comment: @Rutger Moody : I don't think so because when you talk about a rotation, you implicitly use real coefficients, whereas here, you necessarily need complex numbers.